# Testing yepnope with jasmine and phantomjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to use the karma test runner with a angular web app, running jasmine inside phantomjs.

In my code I want lazyload a javascript file and then detect if the file has been loaded.

I have a angular service which uses yepnope.js to load the javascript file like so:

```
service.load("file.js").then(function(){
    //assert if file is loaded
});
```

Running the test, I just get a 404 in phantomjs log, I've tried placing the file multiple places in the karma config but it always returns 404

Anyone know of a way to expose a file on a certain url with phantomjs and karma?

ps. also tried running the test with chrome, with same result.